# Customtkinter: why does this event.widget lose the proper grid information?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

In an UI I'm trying to make I want to make an interactive matrix where some data should be entered by the user. Apart from the data value Entries, each column and row has an Entry with a placeholder text where the user should enter the name of the column (e.g. price) and row (e.g. a company). In order to generate the matrix I have this class method

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import messagebox



class AK_Matrix_Frame(ctk.CTkFrame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        
        #initialize the frame class-------------------
        super().__init__(root)
        

        #Set frame properties-------------------------
        self.width = 200
        self.height = 400
        self.grid(row=1,  column=0,  padx=10,  pady=5)


        #Parameters-----------------------------------
        self.m = 2
        self.n = 3

        #initialize and set up reference dict----------
        self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict ={}
        self.gen_matrix()
        
        #Base Button-----------------------------------
        read_button = ctk.CTkButton(self, text = "Read", command = self.read_matrix)
        read_button.pack(pady=12, padx = 10)

        root.mainloop()


    def gen_matrix(self):
        

        matrix_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text = "Anbieter-Kategorien Matrix", font= ('Ariel', 18))
        matrix_label.pack(pady=12, padx = 10)
        
        self.matrix_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self, width=200, height=200)
        self.matrix_frame.pack( padx=10,  pady=5,  expand=True)
        

        self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(0,0)] = ctk.CTkLabel(self.matrix_frame, text = "A\K", font= ('Ariel', 14))
        self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(0,0)].grid(row = 0,  column = 0,  padx = 5,  pady = 5,  sticky='w'+'e'+'n'+'s')
        

        for i in range(self.m):
            
            
            self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(i+1,0)] = ctk.CTkEntry(self.matrix_frame, placeholder_text = "Anbieter{a}".format(a = i+1), font= ('Ariel', 14))
            self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(i+1,0)].grid(row = i+1,  column = 0,  padx = 5,  pady = 5,  sticky='w'+'e'+'n'+'s')
            self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(i+1,0)].bind("<Return>", self.replace_matrix_entry_w_label)

            for j in range(self.n):


                if i == 0:
                    self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(0,j+1)] = ctk.CTkEntry(self.matrix_frame, placeholder_text = "Kategorie{k}".format(k = j+1), font= ('Ariel', 14))
                    self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(0,j+1)].grid(row = 0,  column = j+1,  padx = 5,  pady = 5,  sticky='w'+'e'+'n'+'s')
                    self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(0,j+1)].bind("<Return>", self.replace_matrix_entry_w_label)

                self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(i+1,j+1)] = ctk.CTkEntry(self.matrix_frame, font= ('Ariel', 14))
                self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(i+1,j+1)].grid(row = i+1,  column = j+1,  padx = 5,  pady = 5,  sticky='w'+'e'+'n'+'s')



    def read_matrix(self):

        pass


    def replace_matrix_entry_w_label(self, event):
        print(event.widget.grid_info())
        i = event.widget.grid_info()["row"]
        j = event.widget.grid_info()["column"]

        print(event.widget)

        print("Row, Column:",i,j)

        txt = event.widget.get()

        print("Event widget contains:",txt)

        event.widget.destroy()

        self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(i , j)] = ctk.CTkLabel(self.matrix_frame, text = txt, font= ('Ariel', 14))
        self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(i , j)].grid(row = i,  column = j,  padx = 5,  pady = 5,  sticky='w'+'e'+'n'+'s')




AK_Matrix_Frame(ctk.CTk())
```

The matrix displays without problem and all entries and labels are placed in the correct location. But when the class method self.replace_matrix_entry_w_label is called, the grid information is transmitted falsely.

And this is the output for any fringe column or row entry I enter text and press return:

```
{'in': <customtkinter.windows.widgets.ctk_entry.CTkEntry object .!ak_matrix_frame.!ctkframe.!ctkentry2>, 'column': 0, 'row': 0, 'columnspan': 1, 'rowspan': 1, 'ipadx': 0, 'ipady': 0, 'padx': 6, 'pady': (2, 3), 'sticky': 'nesw'}
Row, Column: 0 0
Event widget contains: 23def
```

So the text one writes in is read correctly, but the row and column are wrong (always 0,0 no matter where the widget is located).
I had the code almost identically with tkinter instead off customtkinter, and then it worked.

Why is the row and column in grid_info() not correct?

I tried accessing the bound widgets `event.widget.grid_info()` in order to get row and column position and use that to replace the Entry with a Label. What actually happens is that the row and column values are always 0,0, no matter which entry in the matrix I select. Since the text written in the Entry is actually correct I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Please try to group all of your code in a single block, and make sure we're able to run it and reproduce the problem. For help on creating the example, see [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley I edited it to be reproducible directly.

Comment: A `customtkinter.Entry` is actually a `tk.Frame` with a child `tk.Entry`.  The entry widget is put using `.grid(row=0, column=0, ...)` inside the frame.  The `bind()` function is bound with the child entry widget, that's why you always get *row 0 and column 0*.  If you want the grid info of the container frame, use `event.widget.master.grid_info()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because customtkinter's `CTkEntry` widget internally creates a tkinter `Entry` as an attribute of itself.

`event.widget` does not refer to the `CTkEntry` that has a row and column number in your grid, but instead refers to the `Entry` that this `CTkEntry` contains.

Your code in the function `replace_matrix_entry_w_label` asks for the position of `Entry` in its parent. But the parent is a `CTkEntry` widget and the only location is `(0,0)`. The code works if you ask for the `grid_info()` of the master of `Entry`, that is of `CTkEntry`. Like this:

```
def replace_matrix_entry_w_label(self, event):
   
        i = event.widget.master.grid_info()["row"]
        j = event.widget.master.grid_info()["column"]

        print("Row, Column:",i,j)

        txt = event.widget.get()

        event.widget.master.destroy()

        self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(i , j)] = ctk.CTkLabel(self.matrix_frame, text = txt, font= ('Ariel', 14))
        self.AK_Widget_Matrix_dict[(i , j)].grid(row = i,  column = j,  padx = 5,  pady = 5,  sticky='w'+'e'+'n'+'s')
```

For the same reason as described above, if you don't destroy `event.widget.master` you will still have an empty shell of `CTkEntry` where just the internal `Entry` is destroyed, but the object still lives on your UI.